# Android Studio Adding image asset not working

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

I'm trying to add an image in Android studio by right clicking on the drawable folder->new->Image Asset, I add an Action Bar and Tab Bar icon with a custom image and I click finish and it looks like its doing something but nothing appears in the drawable folder.  I'm also unable to reference the new image name in any xml.  What's funny is if I go to re-add this image, it says the image already exists and it will be overwritten.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please check if the image asset was created in alternate drawable configuration folders, like drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi.

Comment: as a starter, you can browse go to your project location, then at src/main/res, you can check if the file is actually getting saved. If yes, then to which drawable folder.

Comment: Image won't go in any xml folder but it will be in one of the child folders of drawable. Pls ensure that you have only png and jpg images.

Comment: I figured it out, It looks like the last step right before finish, you can choose Res Directory and by default src\main\res\layouts\custom_row was chosen.  I had to change it to src\debug\res

Answer (score 1):

I create a new project with Android Studio and generate image asset in the new project. It begins to work. I don't know what's wrong with the previous project. Hope it also helps for you.

Answer (score 0):

As @Varun said, Before click on Finish, check save path by click on "Next" button.

Answer (score 0):

TLTR: fix any other icon type you touched before.

In my case it was because of wrong path to foreground image path (the source image was deleted):

[image]

So even after changing the icon type the error does not disappear (buttons are disabled):

[image]

So fix other icon types.

Answer (score -2):

In Background Layer set Asset Type to "Color"