# Cannot click next in Asset Studio when creating an icon

Tags: android, android-studio

Not sure where to post this issue I have with Android Studio IDE, I hope it can be answered here.

When I open the Asset Studio in Android Studio by right clicking on my Android Module and selecting `new -> Image Asset` I cannot get past the first screen. Even when I leave this default, when I try and press next the Asset Window start shaking shortly after a second or two.

- I encountered this problem with a prior version of Android Stuido but an update to the latest version did not help.
- I tried updating the android SDK and build tools since they are obviously related but without success.
- I tried restarting Android Studio but the "bug" still remains.

Perhaps I am doing something wrong, [I created a video of my workflow and the issue I am encountering](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaPdTwuRlrM).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I had the same problem.

In the `Legacy` tab, I set the `Google Play Store Icon` to `No` and I could pass the first screen.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer ^ Thanks Amir :)

Comment: This fixed the same problem for me on Android Studio 3.5.3... amazing that we still have this bug in the editor!

Comment: ...but what if your objective is all about making a new play store icon?

Comment: This didnt work for me, Next button still doesnt work, multiple computers, multiple versions of Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem while I was trying to create adaptive icon from vector graphics.

What helped me was that I need to set `Size` to `108 dp x 108 dp` when I imported Vector Asset (`res -> right click -> New -> Vector Asset`).

Comment: I tried to import a 7x128px svg - "next" button would just shake the dialog - no message. I changed to 32x128px and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue with vectors that had a dashed line. Android Studio doesn't support dashed-strokes by default. You can check what is not supported in this link [Dashes stroke-dasharray in Android Vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45893855/dashes-stroke-dasharray-in-android-vector/47158885#47158885). So in such cases Android Studio just doesn't show any error upfront.

In your case I see its happening even for normal vectors.

To check why its failing notice every time it fails the exclamation mark at the extreme bottom right of Android Studio turns red and flashes. Just close pop up window of Android Studio and click on the red exclamation mark. It will give you the reason why its failing. Although there was nothing much I could do about it maybe you can figure out whats wrong.

Comment: Thumbs up for the exclamation mark at the bottom right check. Didn't know about that.

Comment: Saved my day! Thank you so much! (checked the error at exclamation mark in the right corner)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been answered but here's another thing that might fix someone else's problem when adding an asset and getting the weird shaky window error: **check the asset dimensions you're importing**.

I was trying to add a Vector Asset with dimensions about `23dp x 1077dp` (**really big height and small width**), and for some reason Android Studio didn't accept it. After changing it to a dimension bigger than `170dp x 8137.3dp` (it scales automatically) it worked. Then I went on the .xml file and changed it to a dimension I wanted, preserving the proportion of mostly 200dp in width or height as prompted by Lint in a warning.

I don't really know why it worked but I managed to add the asset. If anyone knows it, feel free to explain.

Comment: Thanks really helped. Was the same case. after setting one of the dimesions to 6000dp and rounding the other to 220dp it went through just fine. The reduced the size back in XML

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1) Have you tried setting it manually through file explorer/directories etc.?

2) Maybe try a drawable importer? [Like this.](http://www.javahelps.com/2015/02/android-drawable-importer.html)

3) Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140585/android-studio-adding-image-asset-not-working), it might help.

4) Try completely uninstalling Android Studio, re-download and install again, if all else fails.

Answer (score 0):

As per your project structure, I believe this is not a native application.

That's right, Flutter projects are not Android projects. Many Android tools are enabled only for projects that have an Android facet. Adding that to Flutter projects causes many problems, so we don't do that and this functionality available for only in **native android application**.

Furthermore,If you want to use may be it'll help you.

Open `android studio File->Open folder->navigate` to your flutter project and select the Android folder. Wait for it to sync, then navigate inside the Android studio folder and find the res folder right click on it and choose New you will see the Image asset studio.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and the problem was that the **dimensions of my source image were too small**, which I think is the takeaway from all the other answers as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was caused by some unusual project structure, including some source directories added manually within the module.

The only solution was to create a new sample project in Android Studio, use the Asset Editor, generate all the assets to finally copy those to my "unusual" project.

One could also read the IDE (Android Studio) logs to see exception that are being thrown when the editor windows shakes as it's described by the Author of this thread.