# can't add vector to project in android studio 4.1 update

Tags: java, android, vector, icons

I want to add new vector to my project. I followed these steps
right click on the drawable->new->vector assets[image]

then a got this configure vector asset panel. then i select clip art and i got the following window[image]
it says nothing to show. how can i select another icon. please help

Comment: Select clip art radio button then on selected, click on the small icon of android besides Clip Art:
No need to click on the clip art radio button again. For selecting diferent icon click on that small andoid icon preview.

Comment: that also gives the same

Comment: are u connected to internet?

Comment: yeass i m connected

Comment: Clean -> rebuild -> File - Invalidate/Restart

Comment: 7:50 PM Plugin Error: Plugin "Dart" is incompatible (until build 191.SNAPSHOT < AI-201.8743.12).                        got this error in event log

Comment: disable dart plugin if u dont need it then or else update it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223036/discussion-between-randie-pathirage-and-prajwal-waingankar).

Comment: Similar to this issue posted here with a video: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51083538/cannot-click-next-in-asset-studio-when-creating-an-icon/51084718

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. It will help you.

```
    android {
         ...
         defaultConfig {
         ...
            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: While it's true that the useSupportLibrary flag needs to be true for vector assets to be included in your app, it's not true that this flag will enable showing the ClipArt library in the Add Vector Asset dialog.